# Typescript compile on save is not working when tsconfig.json is in project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I can't make visual studio to run typescript compilation to js when I save.

[image]

I have an xproj (asp.net core with net framework)
TypeScript 2.0.3 tools for Visual studio 2015 update 3.

I have tried to enable `"watch" : true` in tsconfig.json but it says that current host is not supported.

I went to Tools > Options > Text Editor > TypeScript > Project and enabled "automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of project"

[image]

Still, changes in .ts files will be reflected in .js files only during compilation, but only when there are changes in c# sever-side files that has to be compiled.

**EDIT:** I have figured out that simple existance of tsconfig.json in the project directory will prevent compilation on save even if the config file is empty.

Can that be fixed somehow currently?

This is the content of my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "diagnostics": true
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**EDIT 2**: I also tried:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "diagnostics": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and it didn't do anything.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Furthermore intellisense is not working anymore since the installation of Update 3 and Typescript 2.0.3. Anybody has a solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2015 and Typescript 2.0.3. Then I reinstalled Visual Studio 2015. After opening my solution and checked Typescript 1.8.3, I installed Typescript 2.0.3 and added "compileOnSave" before "compilerOptions". Since then it works for me. You need to restart Visual Studio after adding this option.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
}
```

Comment: You need to restart Visual Studio! That is one small bugger! Thanks @Bluesight

Answer (score 4):

Adding `"compileOnSave":true` to *tsconfig.json* should do the trick:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
  ...
```

Comment: I also thought so, but this is a default option, and it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Set tsconfig.json compileOnSave to true

```
{
   "compileOnSave": true,

   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",...
 }
}
```

When using Visual Studio a restart of Visual Studio is required.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of the existing answers.

Answer (score -3):

Add the compileOnSave to tscnfig.json will resolve this Problem.

```
{
   "compileOnSave": true,

   "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es5",
     "module": "commonjs",...
 }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of the existing answers.