# How do i stop visual studio 2017 from building on save

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I am unsure what has happened, but i restarted my VS2017 Enterprise and it has been building the entire solution each time i save. I have tried going into Tools > Options but i cannot figure out where the option to disable this is. I also have ReSharper installed. Not sure if that is the issue.

Comment: You probably should check if you installed some VS extension.

Comment: Is this TS compilation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702132/typescript-compile-on-save-is-not-working-when-tsconfig-json-is-in-project

Comment: @ closevoter: "software tools commonly used by programmers" are [explicitly ON-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have Continuous Testing enabled via ReSharper. In particular, it is configured to `On 'Save' Build and...`

To disable it, go to the menu option **ReSharper->Unit Tests->Continuous Testing**

[image]

And then select the option you desire from the **Mode** drop down on the popup window toolbar

[image]

Comment: How do you do this in Visual Studio 2019? I can't seem to find the ReSharper option you are talking about.

Comment: @JasonAyer You could give this JetBrains page a read: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotcover/Continuous_Testing.html#modes

Comment: I managed to turn it off by going to Extensions => Resharper => Options => dotCover => Continuous Testing and changing 'Automatically start tests in continuous testing sessions..." to Build instead of Save. I also had to turn this off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924591/visual-studio-2019-disable-auto-building-solution-on-save