# Visual Studio 2019 disable auto-building solution on save

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 enterprise to work on a .NET project. I wasn't noticing it before, but it seems like every time I am saving a file, the solution is building. I am inferring this because when I save, I can see a number with a red X next to it in the bottom pane. And if i click on the bottom pane, it will open up a console showing me build errors. This changes every time I save.

This is an annoying "feature". I searched for multiple solutions, but none of them work. The "code analysis" option for a solution is deprecated, so you can't change it. I don't have any abnormal extensions either, so this looks like a VS feature.

Comment: You can have several windows docked at the bottom. Which one are you looking at that shows "*build errors*"?

Comment: It's the pane that shows your zoom level, number of build errors, and left/right scroll. If I click on it it shows a  window for build errors.

Comment: Does that window have a caption like Output, Error List etc? In my layout the zoom level and h-scroll are on the status bar of the editor, while the number of build errors does not show there.

Comment: Yeah you're right, the caption is "Error List". When that tab is closed, it shows a number of errors. When you click on the tab, it shows the full errors. They have to be build errors right?

Comment: No, those are not build errors (too long for a comment, posted as an answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when I save, I can see a number with a red X next to it in the bottom pane. And if i click on the bottom pane, it will open up a console showing me build errors.

As clarified in the comments, what opens is the Error List, which by default displays both build *and* IntelliSense errors. There is no automatic build taking place when saving files, but IntelliSense *does* auto-update while editing, and displays the errors it finds in the Error List.

[image]

To stop Intellisense from reporting errors in the Error List, choose the Build Only option in the dropdown circled in red.

Comment: Excluding IntelliSense from the Error List is a good idea because IntelliSense makes so many mistakes. However, the automatic build does occur if the web server (like IIS) is running with the projects from the current solution. And it detects false errors like IntelliSense! This may be annoying. You can stop it by changing `Options->Projects and Solutions->ASP.NET Core->Auto build and refresh option`. Or you can simply kill the web server while editing.

Comment: @AlexFainshtein That is correct, but the OP never mentioned the question is about an ASP project. Reason once again why it's a good idea to post all relevant information and use the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 76):

Another one but very similar cause of the automatic rebuild and restart is `Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes` option under the `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> ASP .NET Core` settings.

Just set it to `None` or any other option than `Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and annoying behavior with Visual Studio 2019.

Every time I am saving a file, the solution is building.

If you have a big solution and project, this is a great loss of time.

If you forget a simple semicolon, correct, ctrl+s to save and boom: automatically Visual Studio start the Build
The solution: **disable code analysis for .NET.**

Follow this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/disable-code-analysis?view=vs-2019

The steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Properties
3. Code Analysis tab
4. Uncheck "Run on build" and "Run on live analysis"
5. Save. (probably it start the build for the last time)

That's all

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. All four checkboxes are disabled, but the VS is still rebuilding on each save.

Comment: Looks like I found the real cause of this issue. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> ASP .NET Core` and select `None` or any other option than `Auto build and refresh browser after saving changes`

Comment: Yess!! You're right! Your solution is better! It does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2022, with the Hot Reload feature, there is an option that allows applying the code and restarting the application on save

[image]

More information about Hot Reload can be found here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/update-on-net-hot-reload-progress-and-visual-studio-2022-highlights/

Enabling/Disabling it will change whether the application re-builds