# Disable automatic build after saving Visual Studio solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If I save my VS solution, then after a second or two, it decides it should rebuild. I find this highly annoying. At that point, I am typically in the middle of typing something. It therefore causes a build error. Even worse, at the end of the build, I frequently lose context in whatever file I am typing. So part of what I was typing doesn't make it into that file.

Can I disable this automatic build?

Comment: Really!  I've never seen that before and I don't see anything in the options like that.  How do you _"save my VS solution"_?  Do you click a button, use a key-combination or do something with a menu?  If you pull down the Build menu, what does the "Build Solution" entry have as a short-cut key?

Comment: This surely isn't the default bevaviour, so you must have somehow (unknowingly) enabled this. Maybe with some extension. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183466/how-do-i-stop-visual-studio-2017-from-building-on-save) it was caused by ReSharper

Comment: (duplicate link courtesy of @derpirscher)

Comment: It's a start. Tells me where not to look. I'll try disabling extensions willy-nilly and see if that helps.

Comment: Answer from quabaam's comment was dodbrian's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61924591/visual-studio-2019-disable-auto-building-solution-on-save